kafka-client 2.7.0 use SASL connet kafka2.2, first time send message throw TimeoutException Topic *** not present in metadata after 1000 ms
kafka-client version 2.7.0
kafka version 2.2
producer config
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(); 
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "server1:19000,server2:19000,server3:19000");
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retries); 
props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 5000); props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class); props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);    
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "config/kfk-sec/client.truststore.jks");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "config/kfk-sec/client.keystore.jks");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, "JKS");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "config/kfk-sec/kafka_cilent_jaas.conf");`

when restart producer, send message will throw
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topic1 not present in metadata after 1000 ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:363)
    at fun.linhui.learning.kafka.KafkaSender.lambda$new$0(KafkaSender.java:48)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topic1 not present in metadata after 1000 ms.

Kafka's domain name is configured in the hosts file.
I tried deleting the dns configuration in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0, deleting the nameserver configuration in /etc/resolv.conf, and service network restart.
it does not work
what should i do to make make kafka-client using sasl send messages faster for the first time? 30s is too long

You shouldn't use hosts files to control kafka connections

Why is that? Can you explain the underlying principle to me?

It overrides your DNS server settings, and conflicts with how Kafka actually advertises itself. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

I found the problem. When SSL handshaking occurs, the Kafka broker performs a reverse DNS lookup on the client's IP address. The timeout occurs during this process, so we must configure the client's IP and hostname in the Kafka broker's hosts file to restore normal operation.
